# Does Tensorflow work for CNN regressor with 2 outputs

Tags: tensorflow, regression

For CNN (or regular NN), if defining 2 outputs, output layers are different (weights) for each output.  2 following cases seem work (converge), but not sure if it is right thing to do. How  error is propagated in following cases?

1) If defining as followings, errors of 2 outputs are averaged and then backpropagated from 2 outputs layer with same error, then to rest layers, during training?

```
   logits = output(full, num_outputs)
   output = tf.tanh(logits)
   cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, output))) 
   optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(cost)
```

2) If defining cost as following, error from each output is  backpropagated from each output layer (errors are different from each output) and then to rest of layers during training?

```
   cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, output)), 0)
```

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do 2 outputs might or might not make sense. For example, for classification problems it is common to have the number of outputs match the number of classes (i.e. MNIST has 10 classes, so your net will have 10 outputs) and treat it as one-hot encoded answer, but with confidence levels rather than 0s and 1s.

Comment: It's not classification. It's regression. Based on your comments, Tensorflow is able to propagation the error in 2 cases, which may be essentially the same as classification (the way it propagate error). In the end, NN is trained properly. What's the difference between 1) and 2), the error is propagated in Tensorflow? The way to train 2 output regressor make sense?

Comment: It really depends on specifics of your problem. A neural network is a function approximator. It learns to map values from n-dimensional input X into values of m-dimensional output f(X). If you have enough labeled samples, your problem has consistent patterns to it and you design and train your network well, it should be able to accurately predict f(X) for values of X that were not included in the original training dataset, but that are still within the same general realm.

Comment: I understand NN capability. My question is how Tensorflow update weights with errors in 2 cases, both seems work for me. Obviously, Tensorflow update weights differently, as the error definitions are different in 2 cases.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the second question (we discuss the first in the comments, we can continue there). The difference between

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, output)))
```

and

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, output)), 0)
```

is that in the first case the mean is computed over every value in the argument, so it results in a single value. In the second case, mean is computed separately for every item along axis 0. Assuming you are training on batches of samples, the second case will calculate the cost individually for every sample in the batch, where the first case will calculate cost across all the samples.

Looking at the tensorflow sources, it seems that the optimizer handles both cases appropriately, attempting to minimize cost function whether it returns a single or multiple values.

Comment: Many people suggest create 2 CNNs for 2 output. Based on your comments (also my experiments also suggests) Tensorflow is able to minimize cost function correctly. Therefore, if build 1 CNN with 2 outputs, only output layer weights are different, and rest CNN weights are the same. And, trained CNN is able to be trained properly. I never had a chance to compare results: build 2 CNN for 2 outputs (obviously, this definitely work), build 1 CNN with 2 outputs. May be they create 2 CNNs that's able to create same results.

Comment: Still curious how Tensorflow minimize cost from 2 outputs, the 2nd case. It first minimize cost from output 2, all the way, to 1st layer, and then, do the same thing from 2nd outputs? It does to times. But, 1st case only do it once, as there is only 1 output with 1 averaged error.

Comment: Good question. You can browse the related tensorflow code yourself. The base optimizer code lives in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py , but the actual calculation of gradients happens in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py